# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod GoogleDataTransport when installing GoogleMLKit Face Detection

Tags: ios, cocoapods

So I tried to install ML Kit Face Detection library by following [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/ios), so first I added this line in my `podfile`:

```
pod 'GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection'
```

Unfortunately after I tried to install it I got this error on terminal:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport":   In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (= 2.0.1, ~> 2.0)

  In Podfile:
    GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection was resolved to 0.60.0, which depends on
      GoogleMLKit/MLKitCore (= 0.60.0) was resolved to 0.60.0, which depends on
        MLKitCommon (~> 0.60.0) was resolved to 0.60.0, which depends on
          GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (~> 1.2)

Specs satisfying the `GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (= 2.0.1, ~> 2.0), GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (~> 1.2)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

And I added more pod like this:

```
pod 'MLKitCommon'
pod 'GoogleMLKit/MLKitCore'
```

But now I got this error on the terminal:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleDataTransport":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    GoogleDataTransport (= 5.1.0, ~> 5.1)

  In Podfile:
    GoogleMLKit/MLKitCore was resolved to 0.60.0, which depends on
      MLKitCommon (~> 0.60.0) was resolved to 0.60.0, which depends on
        GoogleDataTransport (~> 3.2)

Specs satisfying the `GoogleDataTransport (= 5.1.0, ~> 5.1), GoogleDataTransport (~> 3.2)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

After a bit of research I tried to run `pod install --repo-update` but it still give me that error. Is there anyway to resolve this?

Comment: Does anyone still having such problem? In my case both solutions don't work and it says 'None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency'

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This fixed the problem for me:

1. `pod deintegrate`
2. `sudo gem install cocoapods-clean`
3. `pod clean`
4. `pod setup`
5. `pod install`

Comment: Tested and working perfectly for  Xcode 14.0.1, minimum Deployment target iOS 13

Comment: For some reason now `pod clean` is not a command anymore so I had to change it to `pod cache clean -all`

Answer (score 3):

I deleted `Podfile.lock` and ran `pod install`. Worked.

Answer (score 1):

The above two methods did not work for me. I was using Firebase "cloud_firestore: 2.2.0" with "google_ml_kit: ^0.6.0". Turns out cloud firestore(2.2.0) requires FirebaseSDK version 8.0.0. I had to downgrade to 2.0.0 and pasted "$FirebaseSDKVersion = '7.11.0'" at the start of my podfile at ios/Podfile. Here's [a link](https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/issues/27#issuecomment-847121759) to the issue.

Comment: None of the ```pod install``` and others worked for me. Updating dependencies did it for me.